# Count value in dictionary relative to another value

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I have a python dictionary like the one below:

```
{'Jason': {'A': 200, 'B': 'NaN', 'C': 34, 'D': 'NaN', 'E': True},
 'John': {'A': 250, 'B': '34', 'C':98, 'D': 59, 'E': False},
 'Steve': {'A': 230, 'B': '45', 'C':'NaN', 'D': 67, 'E': False},
 'Louis': {'A': 220, 'B': '37', 'C':'NaN', 'D': 'Nan', 'E': True},
 ....
}
```

I want to count the number of `'NaN'` in each value, and return that count with the number of `'NaN'` that have the value `'E': True`.

So I would like to create a dictionary like this:

```
{'A': {'NaN': 0, 'E': 0},
 'B': {'NaN': 1, 'E': 1},
 'C': {'NaN': 2, 'E': 1},
 'D': {'NaN': 2, 'E': 2}}
```

I have this code that returns a dictionary with the count of `NaN`

```
NaNs = {}

for k,v in dict.iteritems(): 
    for i in v:
        if v[i] == 'NaN':
            NaNs[i]=0            
for k,v in dict.iteritems():
    for i in v:
        if v[i] == 'NaN':
            NaNs[i]+=1 

print NaN
```

How can I add the count of `E:True` to it?

Comment: Ok, so where's your code and what's the problem with it?

Comment: I know how to count the number of NaN but I don't know how to add the count of E:True to it.

Comment: @ElenaForres: That doesn't answer jonrsharpe's question.

Comment: I edited the question with more information.

Comment: Right now your code gives a single dictionary like this `{'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'D': 1}`.  Maybe a good first step would be to modify it so that it gives a dictionary of dictionaries, so `{'A': {'NaN': 0}, 'B': {'NaN': 1}, 'C': {'NaN': 2}, 'D': {'NaN': 2}}`

Comment: so to do that you would change `NaNs[i]=0` to `NaNs[i]={'NaN': 0}` and `NaNs[i]+=1` to `NaNs[i]['NaN']+=1`

Comment: Did you get it to work as you wanted in the end?

Comment: @K.Menyah Yes, thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, why don't you try this:

```
dict = {'Jason': {'A': 200, 'B': 'NaN', 'C': 34, 'D': 'NaN', 'E': True},
 'John': {'A': 250, 'B': '34', 'C':98, 'D': 59, 'E': False},
 'Steve': {'A': 230, 'B': '45', 'C':'NaN', 'D': 67, 'E': False},
 'Louis': {'A': 220, 'B': '37', 'C':'NaN', 'D': 'Nan', 'E': True},
 }

NaNs = {}

for k,v in dict.iteritems(): 
    for i in v:
        if i != 'E':
            NaNs[i]={'NaN': 0, 'E': 0}
for k,v in dict.iteritems():
    for i in v:
        if str(v[i]).lower() == 'nan':
            NaNs[i]['NaN']+=1
            if v['E'] == True:
                NaNs[i]['E']+=1

print NaNs
```

I shouldn't really be going around calling variables `dict` and `NaNs`, but I tried to change your code as little as possible.